# Download file from SharePoint using Office365-REST-Python-Client

Tags: python-3.x, sharepoint, office365

I am unable to download file from SharePoint using [Office365-REST-Python-Client](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client#Installation).

I am getting then below error:
office365.runtime.client_request_exception.ClientRequestException: (None, None, "401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: [https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/test/_api/Web/getFileByServerRelativePath(DecodedUrl='%2Fsites%2Ftest%2FShared%20Documents%2FSample_Compliance_content.pdf')?$select=ServerRelativePath,Id"](https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/test/_api/Web/getFileByServerRelativePath(DecodedUrl=%27%2Fsites%2Ftest%2FShared%20Documents%2FSample_Compliance_content.pdf%27)?$select=ServerRelativePath,Id%22))

I have went through multiple documents to download the SharePoint file but none of them worked out. Please help me with this error.

So far I have done following steps:

1. I signed up for free Developer 365 program.
2. Created a site in SharePoint and uploaded a document there.
3. I want to download that document using Office365-REST-Python-Client.
4. For authorization I did all the steps mentioned in the Office365-REST-Python-Client document.

I followed below steps for authentication as mentioned in the Office365-REST-Python-Client.

1. Login to the home page of the Azure Portal
2. Navigate to "Azure Active Directory" using the three bars in the top right corner of the portal
3. Select "App registrations" in the navigation panel on the left
4. Search for and select your relevant application
5. In the application's "Overview" page, the client id can be found under "Application (client) id"
6. In the application's "Certificates & Secrets" page, the client secret can be found under the "Value" of the "Client Secrets." If there is no client secret yet, create one here.

Below is my code snippet

1. I am using ClientCredential to use client id and client secret (not secret id) and ClientContext
2. I want to download the pdf file Sample_Compliance_content.pdf in the SharePoint site
3. But it is giving me the above mentioned error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbKnr.png)

Answer (score 0):

A 401 Unauthorized error in SharePoint API requests typically means that the request lacks proper authentication or the provided credentials are incorrect. To resolve this issue in Python, you'll need to ensure that you're using the correct authentication method and that the credentials you're providing are valid.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason clientID ClientSecret auth is having issues.

Please use certificate auth flow.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread

1. Generate a Private Key: Use OpenSSL to create a private key. The command might look like

```
openssl genrsa -out privatekey.pem 2048
```

2. Create a Certificate Signing Request (CSR): Generate a CSR using your private key with a command like

```
openssl req -new -key privatekey.pem -out csr.pem
```

3. Generate a Self-Signed Certificate: Use the CSR to create a self-signed certificate, with a command like

```
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in csr.pem -signkey privatekey.pem -out certificate.pem
```

Upload the **certificate.pem** to azure and use the **privateKey.pem** to authenticate in the client

[image]